# Set value in xsl-region-before foblock from xml child tag value

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xslt-1.0, apache-fop

I am generating PDF file by XSL & XML file using apache fop, i will get a list of map from database and write it as a XML tag values and PDF template in XSL file, i need to create page by page PDF by using XML tag values. i tried to come out with fo:flow element, but in output values are not set in xsl-region-before, check my files..

**My XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <xsl:template match="pages">
            <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
                <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                        page-height="8.5in" page-width="11in" margin-top=".5in"
                        margin-bottom=".5in" margin-left=".5in" margin-right=".5in">
                        <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" />
                        <fo:region-before extent="2cm" overflow="hidden" />
                        <fo:region-after extent="1cm" overflow="hidden" />
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                </fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple"
                    initial-page-number="1">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                        <fo:block font-size="13.0pt" font-family="serif"
                            padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="4.0pt" text-align="center"
                            border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                            <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="page-header"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                        <fo:block font-size="12.0pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                            padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="2.0pt" text-align="center"
                            border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                            <xsl:text>Page</xsl:text>
                            <fo:page-number />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="page-body" />
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </fo:root>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="page-body">
            <fo:block text-align="center" break-before="page">
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                    border-style="dashed">
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="table-header" />
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="table-data" />
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="table-header">
            <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                border-style="solid">
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-one"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-two"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-three"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="table-data">
            <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                border-style="solid">
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-one"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:if test="number(column-two) = number(column-two)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(column-two, ',','.'), '#,###.##')"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-three"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages>
<page-body>
    <page-header>
    Page Sample 1
    </page-header>
    <table-header>
        <column-one>Column One</column-one>
        <column-two>Column Two</column-two>
        <column-three>Column Three</column-three>
    </table-header>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>5000</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>5000</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>0</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>0</column-two>
        <column-three>Four</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>2000</column-two>
        <column-three>Four</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>1234</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>5666</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>5666</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
     </page-body>
     
     <page-body>
     <page-header>
    Page Sample 2
    </page-header>
    <table-header>
        <column-one>Column One</column-one>
        <column-two>Column Two</column-two>
        <column-three>Column Three</column-three>
    </table-header>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>8000</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>8000</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>100</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>100</column-two>
        <column-three>Four</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>7000</column-two>
        <column-three>Four</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>7000</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>6666</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>6666</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
     </page-body>
</pages>
```

Help me to get and set value for xsl-region-before block from xml tag **page-header**  which is inside the each **page-body** tag.

Expecting output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
            page-height="8.5in" page-width="11in" margin-top=".5in"
            margin-bottom=".5in" margin-left=".5in" margin-right=".5in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" />
            <fo:region-before extent="2cm" overflow="hidden" />
            <fo:region-after extent="1cm" overflow="hidden" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple"
        initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block font-size="13.0pt" font-family="serif"
                padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="4.0pt" text-align="center"
                border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                <fo:block>
                    Page Sample 1
<!--As "Page Sample 2" from xml page-body/page-header value for next page -->
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block font-size="12.0pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="2.0pt" text-align="center"
                border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                Page
                <fo:page-number />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block text-align="center" break-before="page">
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                    border-style="dashed">
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Column One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Column Two</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Column Three</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">5,000.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">5,000.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Four</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">2,000.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Four</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">1,234.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">5,666.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">5,666.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" break-before="page">
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                    border-style="dashed">
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Column One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Column Two</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Column Three</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">8,000.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">8,000.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">100.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">100.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Four</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">7,000.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Four</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">7,000.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">6,666.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                            border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">6,666.0</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                    padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

[image: Kindly refer this image]

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Comment: added image reference @michael.hor257k

Comment: Page-header is not a child of pages which is what you expect in your template

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question. As code, not as image.

Comment: @KevinBrown Yes it cannot be a child, but Is there any option to set different values in page header by reading from xml tags.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have attached transformed output xsl file, but i could not produce code for exactly what i need, i have mentioned as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is a second answer that uses FOP and markers. Slight modification to your XSL only. This uses retrieve-marker in the region-before and sets that marker each time a page-body is encountered:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="pages">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                page-height="8.5in" page-width="11in" margin-top=".5in"
                margin-bottom=".5in" margin-left=".5in" margin-right=".5in">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" />
                <fo:region-before extent="2cm" overflow="hidden" />
                <fo:region-after extent="1cm" overflow="hidden" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple"
            initial-page-number="1">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:block font-size="13.0pt" font-family="serif"
                    padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="4.0pt" text-align="center"
                    border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="header" retrieve-position="first-including-carryover"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block font-size="12.0pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                    padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="2.0pt" text-align="center"
                    border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                    <xsl:text>Page</xsl:text>
                    <fo:page-number />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="page-body" />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="page-body">
    <fo:block text-align="center" break-before="page">
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="header">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="page-header"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:marker>
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
            border-style="dashed">
            <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
            <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
            <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
            <fo:table-header>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="table-header" />
            </fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="table-data" />
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="table-header">
    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
        border-style="solid">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-one"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-two"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-three"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="table-data">
    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
        border-style="solid">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-one"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:if test="number(column-two) = number(column-two)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(column-two, ',','.'), '#,###.##')"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-three"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This yields the following:

[image]

Comment: yes this solution works completely, thanks for your understanding and thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on your design, you can use different page-sequences then because the page-sequence static-content is different for each one and you are breaking the page at the start of each one. You may not want to restart page-numbering and such but maybe you do, I do not know.

You could also use marker/retrieve-marker to pull the content into the region-before, see second answer.

Maybe reorganize like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="pages">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                page-height="8.5in" page-width="11in" margin-top=".5in"
                margin-bottom=".5in" margin-left=".5in" margin-right=".5in">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" />
                <fo:region-before extent="2cm" overflow="hidden" />
                <fo:region-after extent="1cm" overflow="hidden" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="page-body">

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple"
        initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block font-size="13.0pt" font-family="serif"
                padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="4.0pt" text-align="center"
                border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="page-header"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block font-size="12.0pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="2.0pt" text-align="center"
                border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                <xsl:text>Page</xsl:text>
                <fo:page-number />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block text-align="center" break-before="page">
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                    border-style="dashed">
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="table-header" />
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="table-data" />
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>




</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="table-header">
    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
        border-style="solid">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-one"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-two"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-three"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="table-data">
    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
        border-style="solid">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-one"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:if test="number(column-two) = number(column-two)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(column-two, ',','.'), '#,###.##')"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                padding-top="3pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="column-three"></xsl:value-of>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should give the following output:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="8.5in" page-width="11in" margin-top=".5in" margin-bottom=".5in" margin-left=".5in" margin-right=".5in">
        <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm"></fo:region-body>
        <fo:region-before extent="2cm" overflow="hidden"></fo:region-before>
        <fo:region-after extent="1cm" overflow="hidden"></fo:region-after>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple" initial-page-number="1">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <fo:block font-size="13.0pt" font-family="serif" padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="4.0pt" text-align="center" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
            <fo:block> Page Sample 1 </fo:block>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
        <fo:block font-size="12.0pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="2.0pt" text-align="center" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">Page<fo:page-number></fo:page-number></fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block text-align="center" break-before="page">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-style="dashed">
                <fo:table-column border-style="solid"></fo:table-column>
                <fo:table-column border-style="solid"></fo:table-column>
                <fo:table-column border-style="solid"></fo:table-column>
                <fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Column One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Column Two</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Column Three</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">5,000.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">5,000.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Four</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">2,000.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Four</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">1,234.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">5,666.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">5,666.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple" initial-page-number="1">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <fo:block font-size="13.0pt" font-family="serif" padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="4.0pt" text-align="center" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
            <fo:block> Page Sample 2 </fo:block>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
        <fo:block font-size="12.0pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="2.0pt" text-align="center" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">Page<fo:page-number></fo:page-number></fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block text-align="center" break-before="page">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-style="dashed">
                <fo:table-column border-style="solid"></fo:table-column>
                <fo:table-column border-style="solid"></fo:table-column>
                <fo:table-column border-style="solid"></fo:table-column>
                <fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Column One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Column Two</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Column Three</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">8,000.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">8,000.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">100.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Three</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">100.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Four</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">7,000.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Four</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">7,000.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">6,666.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" border-style="solid">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">One</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">6,666.0</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">Five</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

If you remove the initial-page-number (not sure what you want here) and you remove the page-break you are creating, this yields the following:

[image]

Comment: sorry it prints same "Page Sample 1" in all pages, i need to show the value in header from the XML page-body/page-header tags.

Comment: See edit above, not yields two page sequences as needed

Comment: If you really only want one flowing page-sequence that has different headers for the pages but all together then you need to use marker/retrieve-marker to pull the content into the header. You question is not that clear in what your expected out should be